# Streaming from Google music cloud to wireless speaker or airplay

Tags: streaming, google-play-music

On my Google Nexus 7, I want to stream music from the Google cloud to a wireless speaker or airplay. I have found lots of apps that can stream to airplay, but none of them can see my Google music which I have uploaded to the cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to stream your Google Music to any device that is DLNA enabled. It's an android app called [BubbleUPNP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp). What it does is it accesses your Google Music account, adds the titles to your local library (only the titles, think of them as links to the Google Music library) and then starts a DLNA server on your phone. This means that any device that can access DLNA servers can play this music, thus it now also has access to your Google Music tracks.

How to do this:

1. Download the BubbleUPNP app.
2. Buy the BubbleUPNP license (~$4) - well worth the money!
3. Start the app, go to library and select Google Music.
4. Give permission to the app and wait for the scanning process to finish.
5. With the server started on your Android device, access it from any DLNA capable device (TV, PC, Smartphone, Tablet, etc.). In the Music section you should now also see your Google Music tracks.

Downside is the fact that you can't "send" a track from Google Music (from your Android device) to be played on the DLNA device but you have to play it from the DLNA device directly.

Hope this helps!